# What does the 'a' do in this MySQL query? It doesn't run without it

Tags: mysql

The 'a' at the end of this:

```
SELECT
email_home
FROM
(SELECT email_home FROM sales
UNION ALL
SELECT email_work FROM sales) a
```

What's it do/for? The code doesn't run without it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It's just an alias.  Mysql requires all sub queries like that require a specific name.  People just use 'a'  as convention if they aren't really going to use it.

You could specify the column name thusly:

a.email_home

Answer (score 0):

It sets the name of an alias to the table to "a".

Presumably, you could reference objects in that table by using "a.[columnName]" for future stuff.

Comment: No he couldn't `[fieldName]` is an invalid identifier in SQL

Comment: You're correct.  It's a column.  Not a field.  And the brackets are just there to show that it should be replaced by an actual existing column.  Like "a.user_name" or "a.id".

Answer (score 0):

As you are using subquery in `From` clause MySql requires alias name. In your case "a" is just a alias given to your subquery in `From` clause. for detail information read [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/from-clause-subqueries.html)